# Get selected row in Gridview yii2 selectioncolumn undefined error

Tags: javascript, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i am getting error while selecting the rows and sending keys to controller.

In firebug on the button click event it displays error something like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectionColumn' of undefined
```

Here is my `view` code. its simple `gridview`

```
<?= Button::widget([
    'label' => 'Message',
    'options' => ['class' => 'btn-danger','id' => 'message'],
]);
?>
</p>

 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'showOnEmpty'=>true,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        [

            'attribute' => 'event_id',
            'label' => 'Event Title',
            'value' => 'event.title'
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'fullName',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'value' => 'users.fullname',
        ],
    ],
]);
?>
```

And here is the script i am using for `onclick` event

```
$script = '
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  btnCheck  = $("#message");
  btnCheck.click(function() {
    var keys = $("#w1").yiiGridView("getSelectedRows");
    alert(keys);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "'.\yii\helpers\Url::to(['/checkin/message']).'",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {keylist: keys}
    });
  });
});';
$this->registerJs($script, \yii\web\View::POS_END);
```

Which doesnt seems to work somehow on the button `onclick` event only instead of that if i use this script it works fine

```
$this->registerJs('
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#w1 input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
            var keys = $("#w1").yiiGridView("getSelectedRows");
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "../message", // your controller action
                dataType: "json",
                data: {keylist: keys},
                success: alert(keys)
            });
        });
    });
```

Which is almost same but in the second script the ajax request is sent every time i click on the checkbox.

I want users to select the rows first and do action on the button click event
Hope you understand
I know its very common error but i tried different options and none of it seems to work

thank you.......

Comment: Can you tell us on which row do you have this error?

Comment: @lajosarpad On every row.. I have a gridview and checkbox column. All i want to do is do some action on selected data from that gridview. Right now it doesnt work on button click event. It works if i use the second script i included in the answer..

Comment: I mean: which row in the source-code.

Comment: @lajosArpad the .click function row when i use `$("#w1 input[type=checkbox]").click(function()` it works fine but when i use `btnCheck  = $("#message"); btnCheck.click(function() ` it doesnt work.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: which row in the source-code throws the exception? If you open the browser console and watch the error, which line of the source-code does it guide you to?

Comment: @lajosarpad it throws exception on `var keys=$("#w1").yiiGridView("getSelectedRows");` line.

Comment: @lajosarpad hey thank you for pointing my attention to that line. I read somewhere on yii forum that we can use `w0 w1` or `w2`. so i tried `w0` and it worked but i did not understand what is the reason behind that. If you know please explain thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see an error message, the first thing you should check the line it is occurring at. There you will find the most important information. In our case, this is the line of code where the problem was:

```
var keys=$("#w1").yiiGridView("getSelectedRows");
```

Here, your code searched for an element having the id of `w1` and called `yiiGridView` for that. Somewhere inside the function a `selectioncolumn` was referred, but the element whose member with that name was referred was not initialized properly.